# How to make Installer as safe against antivirus

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, installation, installshield

We are working on a WPF application. We have created the Installer setup of the application using install shield limited edition. Now ,created installer having some issues with Norton, McAfee, Avast, etc.  They are all not sure if the installer is safe.
How can we solve this issue?  Any help would be appreciable.

Regards,

Ranish

Comment: Details please. What problems are you seeing? What else does this application use, i.e. Does it connect to server, install a back end database, or where does it write files to?

Comment: Actaullay we are downloading the installer setup from a web site and while downloading the setup we are getting a "Could harm your computer" message.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a screenshot. It sounds like a message from your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use code signing for your package, such as verisign. This should provide authentication for the browser and for the OS Platform.

When you author your package, and I have not used InstallShield Express, just the professional and premium versions; however, in the Releases view, you should be able to enter your certificate pfk path and password information.